# Using Java gcm-server to send message to topic

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using Java [gcm-server](https://github.com/google/gcm) to send messages to Android client apps, and I would like to send a message to a specific topic as showed [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging).

My problem is that I only managed to send a message using the Sender class, to a list of registration_ids, and I can't figure out how to use parameter "to": "/topics/myTopic" (I read the source code and it seems it is not implemented).

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,Right Now... Not Implemented yet,

you need to make a HTTP POST request to  :

https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

with body

{ 
  "data": 
{
    "title": "Test Title",
    "message": " Your Message"
  },

**"to" : "/topics/global"**

}

For more Help - 
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/gcmsender/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmsender/GcmSender.java